# Integral where lower limit of integration is an interval

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem I have is:

> Calculate the integral (here $a < -1$)
>
> $$\int_a^{-1} \left( t+\frac{1}{t}\right)\, dt$$

What I tried:

1. Looked up examples, but couldn't find any where one of the limits of integration was given as an interval like it is in this problem. I might not be using the correct terminology, so am stuck at the start.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. You integrate it and you plug in $a$ to the anti derivative? Where is the interval?

Comment: $a$ is not an interval, it's just a variable with a value. All they're doing is telling you that its value is less than -1.

Comment: I just mean where the lower limit of integration isn't an exact number. $a<-1$ in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we find the anti-derivative:
$$
\int\left(t + \frac{1}{t}\right)dt
 = \int t dt + \int \frac{dt}{t}
 = \frac{t^2}{2} + \ln |t| + c.
$$
Thus, for $c<d\le -1$,
$$
\int_c^d \left(t + \frac{1}{t}\right)dt
 = \left[ \frac{t^2}{2} + \ln |t| \right]_c^d
 = \left[ \frac{d^2}{2} + \ln |d| - \frac{c^2}{2} - \ln |c|\right]
 = \frac{d^2-c^2}{2} + \ln \left|\frac{d}{c}\right|.
$$

Can you apply this to your specific problem?

Comment: I follow the first step, but am having trouble understanding the second step. Why is the interval $c<d\le -1$?

Comment: @LovesLinearAlgebra It is a generalization of your integral. In your case, $c=a$ and $d=-1$.

Comment: @LovesLinearAlgebra this may not be true if $c < 0 < d$ for example because at $t=0$ the integrand is problematic..

Comment: But arent we always below $-1$ at the top limit of integration is $-1$ and $a <-1$? So we dont have to worry about evaluating at $0$?